# How to Parse an StdClass object

Tags: php, json

I encoded a `MySQL` table array to `JSON` and insert it to a table in specific `JSON` datatype column because I want to Parse this array into an (HTML table) using PHP of course, so when I run this code block

```
<?PHP
    $stmts = $conn->prepare('SELECT `items` FROM `bills` WHERE id=3');
    $stmts->execute();
    $result = $stmts->fetchColumn();
    $decoded = json_decode($result);
    print_r($decoded);
    foreach ($decoded[0] as $key => $value) {
        echo "<br>Column: ".$key."<br>";
        echo "value: ".$value."<br>";
    }
?>
```

I realized that `$decoded` is a `StdClass` Object and The Output from `print_r` is:-

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => o4
        [2] => Efexor
        [3] => Eklil
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 30
        [6] => 15
        [7] => Phezer
        [8] => Venlafaxine
        [9] =>
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 2020-03-25
        [12] => 2021-08-25
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] => caps
        [17] => ..\upload\Efexor.jpg
        [id] => 1
        [qty] => 15
        [Sale] => 1
        [name] => Efexor
        [bonus] => 0
        [price] => 30
        [company] => Phezer
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\Efexor.jpg
        [owned-com] => Eklil
        [pack-size] => 0
        [codenumber] => o4
        [chemicalcom] => Venlafaxine
        [dosage-form] => caps
        [concentration] =>
        [expiration-date] => 2021-08-25
        [production-date] => 2020-03-25
 )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 2
        [1] =>
        [2] => Efexor
        [3] => Eklil
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 15
        [6] => 10
        [7] => Phezer
        [8] => Venlafaxine
        [9] =>
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 2020-03-25
        [12] => 2021-08-25
        [13] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] => caps
        [17] => ..\upload\Efexor.jpg
        [id] => 2
        [qty] => 10
        [Sale] => 0
        [name] => Efexor
        [bonus] => 0
        [price] => 15
        [company] => Phezer
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\Efexor.jpg
        [owned-com] => Eklil
        [pack-size] => 0
        [codenumber] =>
        [chemicalcom] => Venlafaxine
        [dosage-form] => caps
        [concentration] =>
        [expiration-date] => 2021-08-25
        [production-date] => 2020-03-25
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 3
        [1] =>
        [2] => panadol
        [3] => com2
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 5
        [6] => 12
        [7] => GSK
        [8] => Paracetamol
        [9] =>
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 2020-04-09
        [12] => 2021-02-09
        [13] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 2
        [16] => taps
        [17] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [id] => 3
        [qty] => 12
        [Sale] => 0
        [name] => panadol
        [bonus] => 2
        [price] => 5
        [company] => GSK
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [owned-com] => com2
        [pack-size] => 0
        [codenumber] =>
        [chemicalcom] => Paracetamol
        [dosage-form] => taps
        [concentration] =>
        [expiration-date] => 2021-02-09
        [production-date] => 2020-04-09
    )
    [3] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => codenumber
        [2] => name
        [3] => owned
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 9
        [6] => 1
        [7] => gsk
        [8] => gscom
        [9] => 12mg
        [10] => 3
        [11] => 2020-03-25
        [12] => 2021-02-09
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] => caps
        [17] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [id] => 4
        [qty] => 1
        [Sale] => 1
        [name] => name
        [bonus] => 0
        [price] => 9
        [company] => gsk
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [owned-com] => owned
        [pack-size] => 3
        [codenumber] => codenumber
        [chemicalcom] => gscom
        [dosage-form] => caps
        [concentration] => 12mg
        [expiration-date] => 2021-02-09
        [production-date] => 2020-03-25
    )
    [4] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => d322
        [2] => fsdfds
        [3] => ewfwef
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 3232
        [6] => 222
        [7] => none
        [8] => nonoe
        [9] => nonoe
        [10] => 12
        [11] => 2020-03-25
        [12] => 2021-02-09
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 2
        [16] => caps
        [17] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [id] => 5
        [qty] => 222
        [Sale] => 1
        [name] => fsdfds
        [bonus] => 2
        [price] => 3232
        [company] => none
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [owned-com] => ewfwef
        [pack-size] => 12
        [codenumber] => d322
        [chemicalcom] => nonoe
        [dosage-form] => caps
        [concentration] => nonoe
        [expiration-date] => 2021-02-09
        [production-date] => 2020-03-25
    )
    [5] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 6
        [1] =>
        [2] =>
        [3] =>
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
        [7] =>
        [8] =>
        [9] =>
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 0000-00-00
        [12] => 0000-00-00
        [13] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] => eyedrop
        [17] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [id] => 6
        [qty] => 0
        [Sale] => 0
        [name] =>
        [bonus] => 0
        [price] => 0
        [company] =>
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [owned-com] =>
        [pack-size] => 0
        [codenumber] =>
        [chemicalcom] =>
        [dosage-form] => eyedrop
        [concentration] =>
        [expiration-date] => 0000-00-00
        [production-date] => 0000-00-00
    )
    [6] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 7
        [1] =>
        [2] =>
        [3] =>
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
        [7] =>
        [8] =>
        [9] =>
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 0000-00-00
        [12] => 0000-00-00
        [13] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] =>
        [17] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [id] => 7
        [qty] => 0
        [Sale] => 0
        [name] =>
        [bonus] => 0
        [price] => 0
        [company] =>
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [owned-com] =>
        [pack-size] => 0
        [codenumber] =>
        [chemicalcom] =>
        [dosage-form] =>
        [concentration] =>
        [expiration-date] => 0000-00-00
        [production-date] => 0000-00-00
    )
    [7] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 8
        [1] =>
        [2] =>
        [3] =>
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
        [7] =>
        [8] =>
        [9] =>
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 0000-00-00
        [12] => 0000-00-00
        [13] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] => eardrop
        [17] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [id] => 8
        [qty] => 0
        [Sale] => 0
        [name] =>
        [bonus] => 0
        [price] => 0
        [company] =>
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [owned-com] =>
        [pack-size] => 0
        [codenumber] =>
        [chemicalcom] =>
        [dosage-form] => eardrop
        [concentration] =>
        [expiration-date] => 0000-00-00
        [production-date] => 0000-00-00
    )
)
```

so how can I parse this Object to a (table)

Comment: You don't have an object that you need to parse, you have an array of objects that you need to iterate over. Seems you know how to use `foreach` to iterate over things, and generate HTML output, you just need to iterate over `$decoded` (i.e. `foreach ($decoded as $obj)` and then output properties of those objects to generate a `<tr>`, instead of iterating over only `$decoded[0]`.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of reformatting the `print_r` output for you so that it's maybe more meaningful. The structure is clear now; whatever is sending you this JSON appears to be generating each object with both numeric and string keys, doubling the length of it all. Your code will be easier to maintain if you ignore all the numeric values and reference things as, for example, `$obj->id`, `$obj->codenumber`, etc.

Comment: Also, protip, if you're using `print_r` to add debugging output into something that will be rendered as HTML, wrap that output in a `<pre>` tag so it's readable instead of one long incomprehensible line.

Comment: If you change `$decoded = json_decode($result);` to `$decoded = json_decode($result, true);` you will get a nested array in `$decoded` and your code should work as is.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thanks a lot for those helpful comments, I do what you said but I got into some trouble with `$obj->id` when running this `<tr>$obj->id</tr>`; its output `$object->id` i tried to concatenate like `echo '<tr>'.$object->id.'</tr>'` and nothing shows

Comment: If you're getting that as direct output, then it's either not within PHP tags at all, or you've put it all in a string with single quotes. For the former, try `<tr><?= $obj->id ?></tr>`; for the latter, just replace the quotes around the whole string with double quotes, so that you get variable interpolation.

Comment: @GregSchmidt same problem no output also tried to define a variable `foreach ($decoded as $object) {
        $id = $object->id;
        echo '<tr>'.$id.'</tr>';`

Comment: You'll need to show enough code to provide context around what's failing.

Comment: Not that `<tr>some output</tr>` is actually valid HTML, though... `<tr><td>output</td><td>output</td>...</tr>` is how you make a table. But show your code and we'll correct what's wrong there.

Comment: @GregSchmidt `$result = $stmts->fetchColumn();
    $decoded = json_decode($result,true);
    foreach ($decoded as $object) {
        $id = $object->id;
        echo '<html><head><title></title></head>';
        echo '<body><tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$id.'</t>';
        echo '</tr></body>';
    }`

Comment: You've taken @Nick's suggestion about adding `true` to the decode call, which means that you now have arrays instead of objects, so `$object->id` won't work any more. That should issue a warning, I'd have thought. Do you have error reporting turned on?